# "Error: sender account not recognized" when calling transferFrom() on an ERC721 contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, erc-721, truffle-test

I am having an issue transferring ownership of an ERC721 token to a deployed Holding contract.

The error I’m getting when running `truffle test` is the following - `Error: sender account not recognized` When calling the `transferFrom()` function on the ERC721 contract using the deployed Holding contract.

I have successfully approved the Holding contract before calling `transferFrom()` so that is not the issue, but I’m unaware where the error is in trying to transfer the NFT to the Holding Contract.

The contracts and test file are located here:
https://github.com/sharad-s/DAOjo

The specific line of code which is causing this error in my tests is line 120 of `DAOjo/test/test.js`

To recreate this error:

- Clone repo
- Install truffle globally
- Run a ganache local blockchain instance (port 8545)
- Run `truffle test` in the root of this repo

Following is the error stack trace:

```
Contract: Crowdsale
DAOToken
1e+23
      ✓ should have a total supply of: 1e+23
      ✓ should have transferred 1e+23 to Crowdsale
    Crowdsale
Wei Raised:  1000000000000000000
Buyer Balance:  1000000000000000000
      ✓ should accept ETH payments (144ms)

Contract: NFTTokenMetaDataEnumerableMock
  NFT Registry
      ✓ Should have a total of 0 tokens when created
NFT APPROVED FOR:  0x3a0a837952964bdf3e751ba838e04b9a1752d94a
HOUSE OWNER:  0x6e4679ddb735556a47dd548489dfab641752afd5
SPV:  0x3a0a837952964bdf3e751ba838e04b9a1752d94a
DAO TOKEN BALANCE OF BUYER 1:  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 3, c: [ 1000 ] }
      1) Should approve and transfer token to SPV contract

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    Transfer(from: <indexed>, to: <indexed>, value: 1000)
    Transfer(from: <indexed>, to: <indexed>, value: 1000)
    Transfer(from: <indexed>, to: <indexed>, value: 1000)
    Transfer(from: <indexed>, to: <indexed>, value: 0)
    Approval(owner: <indexed>, spender: <indexed>, value: 0)

    ---------------------------


  4 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: NFTTokenMetaDataEnumerableMock
       NFT Registry
         Should approve and transfer token to SPV contract:
 Error: sender account not recognized
  at Object.InvalidResponse (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
  at /Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
  at /Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/sharad/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only send transactions `from` an account your node (ganache, in this case) knows the private key for. In this code:

```
const transferFrom = await _HouseNFTRegistry.transferFrom(
    houseOwner,
    _spvHoldingCrowdsale.address,
    1,
    { from: _spvHoldingCrowdsale.address, to: _HouseNFTRegistry.address }
);
```

you're trying to send a transaction from the address of a contract, which you can't do. (No one knows the private key for that address.)

Comment: Got it, thank you! 

I solved this by calling the transferFrom() function {from : houseOwner} which i defined as address[0] given from ganache, who also owned the NFT meant for transfer.